# Removing last word from an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to remove the last word of an input value using the following code:

```
$('#buttonid').on('click',function () { 
    var textVal = $('#inputid').val();
    $('#inputid').val(textVal.substring(0,textVal.length - 1));
});
```

This code removes only one letter from the word. I know I can delete the whole word by specifying the number of its letter in `textVal.length - 1`. However, the word is not static, so I want to use something that removes any **last word** in the input value.

> **Edit**, Note: Words are separated by dots, not spaces.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Split on space, remove the last element, and glue back the sentence. Alternatively, just find the last space and cut everything after it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) method to find a position of the last dot separating last word:

```js
$('#buttonid').on('click', function () {
    var textVal = $('#inputid').val();
    $('#inputid').val(textVal.substring(0, textVal.lastIndexOf('.')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="buttonid">Remove</button>
<input type="text" id="inputid">
```

You can also make your code a little cleaner if you don't reselect the same element again but use a function in the `val` method:

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function () {
    $('#inputid').val(function() {
        return this.value.substring(0, this.value.lastIndexOf('.'));
    });
});
```

Bonus point. If you want you can use very simple regular expression (although it might be overkill here, but regexp is more reliable then `'.'` in `lastIndexOf`) to remove everything after the last word boundary, for example:

```
$('#inputid').val(function() {
    return this.value.replace(/\b.\w*$/, '');
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention words are separated by dots, not spaces. I used your code and it removed the whole input value. I think this because of the dots. Any workaround for this? Thank you @dfsq

Comment: I love the regex answer , because if this was for school or an interview it will be a complete fail trying to explain how they wrote it .... and on the other side if it's for real code then it will probably be the most efficient

Comment: @JerryB For `.` separator use `textVal.lastIndexOf('.')`. And regexp version will not change (another advantage of regexp).

Comment: Awesome! I used your regexp answer and it worked perfect. Thank you very much @dfsq

Comment: @dfsq I'm pretty sure that, while this works, using just `.` in RegEx will match any character between word boundaries. For a literal `.`, it'd be `\.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `lastIndexOf(' ')` instead of `length - 1`. The former will take the last index of a space (which signifies the last word, barring any edge cases you may have) and use it as the end point for your substring.

The latter is supposed to only give you the index of the last letter, since calling textVal.length would result in the number of actual characters in the string, not words.

`$('#inputid').val(textVal.substring(0, textVal.lastIndexOf(' '));`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to transform the text to an array, and [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) it, to remove the last element. Then, rejoining it using space as a separator.

```js
$('#buttonid').on('click', function () { 
    var textVal = $('#inputid').val().split(' ');
    textVal.pop();
    $('#inputid').val(textVal.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputid"></textarea><br>
<button id="buttonid">Remove Word</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lastIndexOf method to get the last index of occurring peroid. Here's the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#buttonid").on('click',function () 
 { 
  //get the input's value
  var textVal = $('#inputid').val();
  var lastIndex = textVal.lastIndexOf(".");
  $('#inputid').val(textVal.substring(0,lastIndex));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="buttonid" value="Go">
</input>
<input type="text" id="inputid" value="Anything.could.be">
</input>
</body>
</html>
```